# How to specify ciao language mode for compilation

Tags: prolog, ciao-prolog

I have the following Prolog program:

```
main :- 
    write("Hello"), nl.
```

Running this under ciao (through compilation `ciaoc` or in a repl `ciaosh`) results in printing the ASCII list representation of this string:

```
[72,101,108,108,111]
```

This, however, works as expected when running under `ciao-shell` with the comment:

```
% -*- mode: ciao; -*-
```

How do I specify the equivalent when running `ciaoc`?

Comment: Look into the documentation of the `double_quotes` Prolog flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As addressed by @paulo-moura above, I misunderstood the significance of single vs double-quotes in Prolog. This code works correctly with single quotes.